# Can't import a module in python 2.7 even though pip says it is installed

Tags: python-2.7, pip, python-imaging-library

I've read the many posts on SO regarding using Pillow or Image instead of PIL but I'm still having trouble with this module.

I'm running this on my MBP on 10.9.5.

I used pip to install image 1.5.5 and Pillow 3.4.2.  However, when I go to import the module in my script, it keeps saying there's no module of that name.

```
first.last@localhost:/usr/local/bin> pip freeze | grep Pillow
Pillow==3.4.2
first.last@localhost:/usr/local/bin> pip freeze | grep image
image==1.5.5
first.last@localhost:/usr/local/bin> which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
first.last@localhost:/usr/local/bin> which python
/usr/local/bin/python

Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named image
>>> import PIL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PIL
>>> import Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Pillow
>>> import pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pillow
```

I checked /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages and it doesn't seem like the .py files are there for pillow or image, even though pip freeze showed that image and Pillow are both installed.

This is the contents of pip is this.  Not sure if it gives any clues to why pip thinks the modules are installed but python says it can't find it.

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
    # EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==9.0.1','console_scripts','pip'
    __requires__ = 'pip==9.0.1'
    import sys
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.exit(
            load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
        )
```

From what I showed in my setup/environment, can anyone point me in a general direction to start fixing this problem?  Is any additional information needed to debug this some more?

Comment: Is there only one version of python running on the box?

Comment: @roymustang86, there's one in /usr/local/bin and the "stock" version in /usr/bin/ but like I showed, the pip and python that i'm running are both from the /usr/local/bin location

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working outside of a virtualenv, the user site should be enabled.  Use the following commands to find the installed location of image and/or pillow:

```
pip show -f image | grep Location
pip show -f pillow | grep Location
```

What you probably want to see is something like:

```
Location: /Users/<your_username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

If it's not installing there, then uninstall and pip install again with the `--user` flag.

Then use the following command to make sure that the results of above will be found in your path:

```
python -m site
```

What you want to see in the output is something like

```
sys.path = [
   ...
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/<your_username>/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/Users/<your_username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

If the installed location is in your user site, and your user site is enabled, then the import will work.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I think this solves the mystery halfway.  Most of my old modules were installed at /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages because of pip 8.x.x.  Pillow and image both are installed at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.  I think for this problem I had tried to update pip from 8.x.x to 9.0.1 because one of the SO links said to use pip 9.  How do I make the Location to be /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages for pip now that installing 9.0.1 changed the value of "Location"?